# Vector laplacian in Curvilinear coordinate systems

Tags: vector-fields

I was taking the electrodynamics course, the instructor says the vector laplacian in cylindrical system satisfies
\begin{align}
(\nabla^2\boldsymbol A)_r&=\nabla^2 A_r-\frac{A_r}{r^2}-\frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial A_\varphi}{\partial\varphi}\\
(\nabla^2\boldsymbol A)_\varphi&=\nabla^2 A_\varphi-\frac{A_\varphi}{r^2}+\frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial\varphi}\\
(\nabla^2\boldsymbol A)_z&=\nabla^2 A_z
\end{align}
but didn't give any derivation. So I wonder how to derive this and also the expression of vector laplacian in spherical coordinates. Also, can this be derived in genral form in any orthogonal curvilinear coordinates, via the **Lamé coefficients**? Specifically, let $x=x(u,v,w)$,$y=y(u,v,w)$,$y=y(u,v,w)$. Define the **Lamé coefficients**
\begin{align}
f&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)^2}\\
g&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\right)^2}\\
h&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right)^2}
\end{align}
and I want to figure out the vector Laplacian $\nabla^2\boldsymbol{A}$ . Thanks for your reading and any helpful answers, but sorry for my poor english.

Comment: You can derive these expressions using covariant derivatives.

Comment: This seems to be the generalisation useful for any metric tensor: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorLaplacian.html. The Lamé coefficients are less general, I think they require orthogonal basis?

Comment: This page also has a lot of information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensors_in_curvilinear_coordinates#Example:_Cylindrical_polar_coordinates